# How to create custom keyboard on my app react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to create a custom keyboard for my app. So I want to disable soft keyboard.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried to follow https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14045 but when I double click on my input keyboard show

Answer (score 2):

U can use packages for that like `react-native-custom-keyboard` or `react-native-keyboard-input` both are help to develop custom keybord in react native app.

react-native-custom-keyboard : https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-custom-keyboard/blob/master/README.md

react-native-keyboard-input : https://github.com/wix/react-native-keyboard-input

Comment: I have two textinput one for the id and one for the password. The first input uses the default keyboard and the second uses custom keyboard. So I just want to disable the keyboard of the second input. The custom keyboard is a numpad with random numbers

Comment: @SamyakBhuta This is an inclusive community. As such not all members speak English natively - we should take care to tolerate this and not berate someone on the basis of grammar, especially when such an answer is a perfectly acceptable solution to the OP's question.

Comment: react-native-custom-keyboard package has a problem. When debugging mode it works fine. But app building time it occurs error:    Task :react-native-custom-keyboard-kit:verifyReleaseResources FAILED